# Request for WSDL returns the website default page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asmx

I'm having a strange problem that I've never seen before.  When I request the WSDL of a new webservice -> https://www.website.com/serviceapp/SVC1.asmx?WSDL <- the request get modified so the URL looks like: -> http://www.website.com/serviceapp/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fserviceapp%2fSVC1.asmx%3fWSDL&WSDL <- which of course results in the 'Resource not found' error.  I'm not an expert by any means when it comes to webservices so maybe this is a simple config issue?  The service application folder resides in the root website folder.  The web.config authentication element looks like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXXYZ" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>
```

could that be part of the problem?  Is the login Url being called regardless of where in the directory I am looking?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add another web.config file to your **serviceapp** folder and add the:

```
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
```

to the web.config in your **serviceapp** folder under the **system.web** node.

This way, anyone has access to **anything** in your **serviceapp** folder, but not in the root of your app.

Right now, I'm assuming that you're using Forms Based Authentication so anyone trying to access any URL of your application gets denied access until they log in. When you allow all users to a specific folder, then they don't need to authenticate.